# how to do linq to sql String Join?

Tags: string, linq, join, linq-to-sql

I want to combine the name of the list in the list.
Error Message : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
dgv.DataSource = this.oFacade.Context.Books
                                         .Include(c => c.Categories)
                                        .Select(c => new dtoObjectDGV
                                        {
                                            ID = c.ID,
                                            Name = c.Name,
                                            CategoryInfo= String.Join(", ", c.Categories.Select(d => d.Name).ToArray())
                                        }).ToList();
```

result : Name = C# Book CategoryInfo = X Category, Y Category,... bla bla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Join` method is not supported in Linq to Entities, I suggest you to project first the info you need and then, using `AsEnumerable` extension method, you can switch to Linq to Object to use `Join` method:

```
DataSource=this.oFacade.Context.Books
                               .Include(c => c.Categories)
                               .Select(c => new 
                                            {
                                               ID = c.ID,
                                               Name = c.Name,
                                               Categories= c.Categories.Select(d => d.Name)
                                             })
                              .AsEnumerable()
                              .Select(c => new dtoObjectDGV
                                            {
                                               ID = c.ID,
                                               Name = c.Name,
                                               CategoryInfo= String.Join(", ", c.Categories)
                                             })
                             .ToList();
```

If your table doesn't have to many columns then you can consider not to do the first projection:

```
DataSource=this.oFacade.Context.Books
                               .Include(c => c.Categories)
                               .AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(c => new dtoObjectDGV
                                            {
                                               ID = c.ID,
                                               Name = c.Name,
                                               CategoryInfo= String.Join(", ", c.Categories.Select(d => d.Name).ToArray())
                                             })
                               .ToList();
```